Is Acumatica 24R1 support Modern ui for Extention screen or customized screen
Is Acumatica 24R1 support Modern ui for Extention screen or customized screen.
I have extend stock item screen in my customization, I have added two new tabs....now I try to convert it to modern ui by convert to moder ui built in convertor.
Once Screen converted modern UI ...I have not seen my customized changes. newly added tabs are not showing.

On the SiteMap page, verify that you have the Type switched to Modern instead of Classic.  Recall too that Modern UI is not yet recommended for a Production environment.  Your web.config should have the new tag set to true:     

Thanks...I have already done this changes...I  have converted my screen to modern ui screen also...but I have extend acumatica screen and  added some new tabs in stock item screen..  which are not showing in modern ui screen.
